# Review Audit bug

Tags: bug, review, review-audits

I was reviewing First Posts on StackOverflow, and then I got this [review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/3190372) (which was a high quality post):
[image]

I noticed two strange things (probably bugs): the "I'm Done" button was enabled, even before I took action, and there was no username displayed.

If this would be the case for all (or many) other review audits, then people would be able to recognize review audits, which is not the intension I suppose.